# proximity alerts on android 4.2

Tags: android, proximity

In my project i'm using proximity alert which is working fine with android 4.1 version(API 16) but on android 4.2( API 17) it wont work . do i need to add some extra flags or something??

```
loctionContex  = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(loctionContex);

Intent intent1 = new Intent(PROXIMITY_ALERT);
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent1, 0);

locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lng, 4, -1, proximityIntent); 

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_ALERT);

 registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
```

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.proximityalert.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please have a look at the following Link
http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/issues/detail?id=2075

Comment: Do you have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission? From the docs: "Before API version 17, this method could be used with ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. From API version 17 and onwards, this method requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission."

Comment: @cermak.cz still no luck :(( i hv added my manifest